# Deno run check Git repository status

Tags: bash, deno

I want to check the status of some external git repositories using Deno. I found the `Deno.run` function which seems like the right function for this case, so I wrote this code snippet to do just that:

```
const cmd = Deno.run({
  cmd: ['git', '--git-dir="GIT_PATH/.git"', '--work-tree="GIT_PATH"', 'status', '--porcelain'], 
  stdout: "piped",
  stderr: "piped"
});

const output = await cmd.output();
const outStr = new TextDecoder().decode(output);
console.log(outStr);
```

But this returns nothing, altough if I run it in my terminal it returns the information just fine. I did notice that this code snippet works fine and returns the right information:

```
const cmd = Deno.run({
  cmd: ['git', 'status', '--porcelain'], 
  stdout: "piped",
  stderr: "piped"
});

const output = await cmd.output();
const outStr = new TextDecoder().decode(output);
console.log(outStr);
```

I also tried to add sudo before the commands (I know, I know) but this didn't solve anything :(

Comment: Are you sure that you have changes in your worktree? If there are no changes, git status --porcelain actually returns nothing.

Comment: Oh, and it's possible that Deno doesn't spawn a shell but runs the git command directly. In that case, you might want to run the command without the double quotes around the directory paths.

Comment: The double quotes around the paths turned out to be the problem! I had them there since I sometimes used paths that contain spaces, now I just fixed that using backslashes. If you could move your comment to an answer I'll mark at as correct (I think that's preferable for you right?)

Comment: Great that it worked! I have moved my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Deno.run` does not spawn a shell but runs the git command directly. Make sure that you don't have the double quotes around the `GIT_PATH` in the final code as these are special shell characters which you don't want in the final argument passed to git.

So the correct code would be:

```js
const cmd = Deno.run({
  cmd: ['git', '--git-dir=GIT_PATH/.git', '--work-tree=GIT_PATH', 'status', '--porcelain'], 
  stdout: "piped",
  stderr: "piped"
});
```

Comment: The more you know!